# How to call an angular component multiple times on the same view?

Tags: angular

I am currently working on an Angular project where we need to use a shared component that displays info twice on the home page. The shared component for displaying this info is changed based on an `@Input() key: string;`.

However what happens is when the component is called twice the first data shows in one of the component calls. After a while the info is just replaced in the same component by the second group of info. The second instance of the component remains blank this whole time.

Here is where the components are called:

```html
<div class="col-md-5">
    <information-panel-small key="home-invest-online"></information-panel-small>
</div>
<div class="col-md-7">
    <information-panel-small key="test-video"></information-panel-small>
</div>
```

This is what my component looks like:

```js
export class InformationPanelSmallComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() key: string;

  infoPanel: InfoPanel;

  constructor(private infoPanelSmallService: InfoPanelSmallService) {
    this.infoPanel = new InfoPanel();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.key != undefined) {
      this.infoPanelSmallService.getSmallInfoPanel(this.key)
        .subscribe(x => {
          if (x != null) {
            this.infoPanel = x.InfoPanel;
          }
        });
    }
  }

}
```

I am not 100% sure this is right but I thought I would at least give it a try before posting on *SO*. My initial thought was, as you can see in the `constructor`, creating a new instance of the class so that with each call of the component it would be completely new but obviously this does not work.

If you have any suggestions I can try I would really appreciate it. Also let me know if I can provide more info. Basically it works but all the info appears in one component and not in two separate components.

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I will try create one

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I am finding it very hard to create something identical.

Comment: Try with `*ngFor` here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-child-interaction-znb5oa

Comment: @PrashantPimpale That looks like an interesting alternative. I will look into applying this to the project. Thanks!

Comment: yup. Try it...!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192621/discussion-between-daniel-bailey-and-prashant-pimpale).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am not sure how it was even half working before but I had not included my service that I was using under the list of `Providers` in my component. So before it looked like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'information-panel-small',
  templateUrl: './information-panel-small.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./information-panel-small.component.scss']
})
```

and afterwards like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'information-panel-small',
  templateUrl: './information-panel-small.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./information-panel-small.component.scss'],
  providers: [InfoPanelSmallService]
})
```

I hope this helps someone in the future with a possibly obvious solution. Thanks for the all the help in the comments!